# Why WM_CHAR is not called in my ListView

Tags: listview, mfc, event-handling, wtl, clistctrl

There is a `WTL::CListViewCtrl`, which is displayed in a Window. When it has the focus, and any key is pressed, the WM_KEYDOWN / UP is called, but the WM_CHAR.

```
class CPopupList : public CWindowImpl<CPopupList, WTL::CListViewCtrl>
{
public:
    DECLARE_WND_SUPERCLASS(NULL, WTL::CListViewCtrl::GetWndClassName())

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CPopupList)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_GETDLGCODE, OnGetDlgCode)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_KEYDOWN, OnKeyDown)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_KEYUP, OnKeyUp)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CHAR, OnChar)
    REFLECTED_NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, OnListItemChanged)
    DEFAULT_REFLECTION_HANDLER()
END_MSG_MAP()

LRESULT OnKeyDown(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);
LRESULT OnKeyUp(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM lParam, BOOL&  /*bHandled*/);
LRESULT OnChar(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);
LRESULT OnGetDlgCode(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM lParam, BOOL&     afx_msg LRESULT OnListItemChanged(WPARAM wParam, LPNMHDR hdr, BOOL&);
...
}
```

Both `CPopupList::OnKeyDown` and `CPopupList::OnKeyUp` are called, but `CPopupList::OnChar` is not.

The `OnGetDlgCode` code is `return DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTCHARS;`

What I found, if I post the WM_KEYDOWN to the Parent window, WM_CHAR is being called in the Parent:

```
LRESULT CPopupList::OnKeyDown(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    ::PostMessage(m_hWndParentCtrl, uMsg, wParam, lParam); -> this will call WM_KEYDOWN + WM_CHAR in parent
}
```

I would like to catch the WM_CHAR here in the ListView. How can I do that, what am I missing?

Comment: You can catch almost all messages with  the virtual function PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg).

Answer (score 2):

`ListView` does not allow *typing* text. Hence, it does not need to *produce* `WM_CHAR`. This particular message is typically translated from keystrokes using the [TranslateMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx) API. Your parent window obviously makes a call to it.

Comment: That is pity, as I need to handle typing (I will jump to the given position, just like a listbox or so). What I do currently, as a workaround, in `WM_KEYDOWN`, I manually translate the key to char by `ToUnicode`, and select that row which matches. Not sure if any better idea to do so. I don't want to catch WM_CHAR in parent and then send back to ListView.

Comment: I suppose you could override the `WndProc` of the `ListView` and make the call to `TranslateMessage` there.

Comment: So you mean, in `WndProc`, if `WM_KEYDOWN` arrives, I just make a call to `TranslateMessage` , which will send a WM_CHAR ?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe not in `WndProc`, but instead before the message is dispatched (don't know where in MFC code that happens). You should *always* make a call to `TranslateMessage`. http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_2.shtm

Comment: Yes, probably then digging into the `WTL` (it's not `MFC`) `ListView` message dispatcher core code, I could do it ... but that looks too much for this now, so I think I prefer my "workaround" described in the first comment.